# Which type of repair level is "DBCC CHECKDB (databasename, repair)"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dbcc

The MSDN's [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) about the command "DBCC CHECKDB" explains three ways to perform a database repair in the syntax section:

```
- REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS
- REPAIR_FAST
- REPAIR_REBUILD
```

But I found the following statement when I was looking for how to repair a suspect database and I can't understand which one of the three modes is it:

> DBCC CHECKDB (*databaseName*, **repair**)

I executed the statement and it works fine. I'm confused because there isn't any reference to the "repair" parameter alone without finish the word with "_allow_data_loss", "_fast" or "_rebuild".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Might be worth putting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ too!

Comment: A good read http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-database-repair/

Comment: I haven't been a DBA in a long time, but this may be a vestige of the old Sybase code.  I know that in some instances it would take shortened versions of the command.  If you run this, what shows up in the log?  I'm pretty sure dbcc still shows up in the error log, and it may show which command executed there, or based on the output of the dbcc, you can figure out which version of the repair ran.

Comment: You may want to contact Paul Randal via twitter or the sqlskills website. He would definitely know.

Comment: @Mike I executed the following statements on a suspect database (I suspect it using these [instructions](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/#comment-1021356):

1)ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET EMERGENCY; 
2)ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET SINGLE_USER;
3)DBCC CHECKDB (databaseName, repair) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
  
4)ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET MULTI_USER;
5)ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET ONLINE;

And I can read in the output of the third statement information about the process but nothing related on the level used.

Comment: @JChao thanks, I wrote the question in the Paul Randal's blog. I hope he answer quickly.

Comment: @agdiaz Please remember to add an answer here when you receive one.  I still think you should put this on http://dba.stackexchange.com too!

Comment: It's true, I'm going to post it in dba.stackexchange.com @RoKa. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying only "repair" as the second parameter in DBCC CHECKDB will be the same as "repair_allow_data_loss". I just ran this on a local instance, and the SQL logs confirm this.